Why does let MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {}; result in an uncaught reference error in javascript?
I'm trying to define a namespace in javscript and I'm following this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespacing-in-javascript/
The first line is:
let MyApp = MyApp || {};

I thought MyApp || {} was to prevent accidental redeclaration of MyApp. But instead this just creates an error. Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined.
Why doesn't this work?

That's what supposed to happen. You can only do this is MyApp exists but is some falsey value. If you want to make the variable exists, the only way to test for that is using typeof, e.g. if (typeof MyApp === `undefined`) { ... }. After all, if it did exist, let a = a would almost certainly be a redeclaration error.

I thought undefined was falsey which would cause it to assign empty object.

You can't access/read MyApp before its declaration. That's the temporal dead zone. It seems like you found out why GFG is considered a garbage platform.

@Legion You can only do that with var, and there's no reason to do it anyway unless you have a really bizarre code structure. Just a bad tutorial IMO.

That line of code does not work. I think it was written by someone remembering how var worked, but with let and const it doesn't make sense.
Variables defined with let and const can't be used before they are declared, or an error is thrown. And since the right hand side is evaluated first, that line of code tries to use the variable (to see if it's falsy) before declaring it (via let MyApp). On the other hand, if it has already been declared, then declaring it again will throw a different error: "Identifier MyApp has already been declared"


let MyApp = {};
let MyApp = MyApp || {}



So whether it already exists or not, the code will throw an error.

When using var to define a variable, this would work. That's because you can access a var before it is defined (it just gets a value of undefined), and you can redeclare vars. (Note: i'm not recommending you use var, just describing it)

Note that the reason you can access a var before it's defined is because of how var is scoped. No matter where in your own code you declare a var, that declaration gets "moved" to the start of the function (if declared inside a function), or global scope. The assignment still happens where you wrote it to happen, but the var itself will already exist. That's super weird scoping, which is why let and const got added (close to a decade ago now =) and follow normal block scoping rules.
